# Having Spring Gradle dependency container before JRE container results in compilation errors

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, gradle-eclipse

I am converting a Java project from Ant to Gradle. The IDE of choice for our team is Eclipse. I have installed the Spring Gradle plugin for Eclipse, applied the Gradle project nature and enabled dependency management. The result is some compilation errors.

The compilation errors occur because the Gradle dependency container is before the JRE container in the eclipse classpath. Some jars on the classpath contain classes that should come from rt.jar (and they are incompatible with our code, presumably older versions).

When dependency management is disabled gradle dependencies come after the JRE container and it compiles without error. This is also consistent with my use of Eclipse/Maven/m2e where the the Maven dependency container comes after the JRE container in eclipse.

Is this the default behaviour for the plugin (putting the gradle container before the JRE)? Is there a way to change it?

I tried to do it in my build.gradle using the eclipse hooks (whenMerged and withXml) but these seem to execute before the gradle dependencies are replaced with the container entry.

Comment: Sounds like the order is "Gradle Dependencies before JRE" is not correct and might be considered a bug. You might want to raise a bugreport here: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS. I have tried to provide some suggestions on how to work around it in my answer below. Even if that works for you, maybe its still worth a bug report?

Comment: Thanks Kris, I have raised a bug. I will also respond to your work arounds.

Comment: For reference the issue raised is https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code to swap the containers. It is probably a little verbose for a couple of reasons. 1. I am new to Groovy coming from a Java background. 2. Gradle is new to myself and the team, I want to be clear about what it is doing.

```
// Swap the order of the JRE and classpathcontainer
// https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4332
task afterEclipseImport(description: "Post processing after project generation", group: "IDE") {
    doLast {
        def cp = new XmlParser().parse(file(".classpath"))
        def container
        def cons = cp.classpathentry.findAll { it.@kind == "con" }
        cons.find {
            if (it.@path.equals("org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.classpathcontainer")) {
                println "found Gradle dependency container"
                container = it
            } else if (it.@path.contains("JRE_CONTAINER")) {
                if (container == null) {
                    println "found JRE container before Gradle dependency container, nothing to do"
                    // Return true to end the loop (return by itself is not enough)
                    return true
                }
                println "found JRE container, swap with Gradle dependency container"
                container.replaceNode(it)
                it.replaceNode(container)
                // Return true to end the loop (return by itself is not enough)
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
        builder.encoding = "UTF-8"
        file(".classpath").withWriter {writer ->
             writer << builder.bind { mkp.xmlDeclaration() }
             def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
             // println cp
             printer.print(cp)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is some controll over the order but it may be not precise enough for you. Right-click on the project and select 'Properties >> Gradle'.

Then select one of the sorting options, such as 'Alphabetically by Path'. After changing this option do a "Gradle >> Refresh All".

If you pick "As returned by BuildScript" which I gather must be what you have. The order will be reversed (Gradle before JRE). There is a bit of a conundrum here that the buildscript does not actually return the "gradle dependencies" container (only its contents) so the order is not really defined by the Build Script.

Unfortunately, you probably have a reason for picking that option and sorting the dependencies inside the container may not actually be a viable solution for you.

If so, there may be a second thing you can try.

When you import the project you the Import Wizard a "Run After" under "Import Options". You might try to use the task specified there to modify the .classpath file at the end of the import (and it will also be executed on refresh).

Finally... one last suggestion. Have you tried [BuildShip](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship)? Maybe it works better for your projects.

Comment: Thanks Kris, I hadn't thought to try changing the sorting options. Setting it to resolve by path (as per your suggestion) works. I am happy to use that as a work around.

I will also have a go at your second suggestion.

With regards BuildShip, it was the first option. Unfortunately I have abandoned it in the short term because of the issue with hard coded file locations in Eclipse settings files. If that is resolved then I will be sure to revisit it. I believe that going forward it will be the best solution.

Comment: " I have abandoned it in the short term because of the issue with hard coded file locations in Eclipse settings files" I trust you made sure there's a BuildShip bug report for that. If BuildShip devs aren't aware this is a problem they aren't likely to fix it.

Comment: Yes, it has already been raised by others. There is some debate around it, I don't think the BuildShip devs consider a bug. For now I am waiting to see what the outcome is. I have added an afterEclipseImport that swaps the JRE and Gradle containers, I am very happy with that as a workaround for now. Thanks for your help.